# Forwarding with postfix: prevent rewriting of from address

Tags: email, postfix

When I send a mail via php mail then postfix  rewrites the from address like this.

For example:

From: info@mydomain

The from becomes: username@myhosthame

How can I stop this from happening? I want postfix to preserve the from address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the domain, you have to set the `myorigin` paramater in `main.cf`. It defaults to `myhostname`.

As to why the user is rewritten, by default `local_recipient_maps` is set to only allow mail from users with an account on the machine, or a defined alias. From `main.cf.default`:

```
local_recipient_maps = proxy:unix:passwd.byname $alias_maps
```

Comment: Thx, setting myorigin = $mydomain works. I am halfway there. I am just trying to figure out now how to replace "username" with ïnfo, so I get the "info@mydomain" email instead of "username@mydomain"

Comment: Found this http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-postfix-masquerade-change-email-mail-address.html